# How to set up Dockerfile for Spring Boot application with JPA database connectivity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am new to Docker and I have a built my REST API but I need to deploy it on Docker. The REST API uses JPA to connect to database. I have tried googling but it's confusing, different people have done different things. Some people have used 2 different containers one, for the Java code and one for MySQL database connectivity, and made them talk to each other. Can anyone possibly suggest a simple docker file that can just run a Spring Boot REST API with JPA database connectivity?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=docker+spring+boot

Comment: You shouldn’t need to do anything special in your Dockerfile.  At deployment time (in your `docker-compose.yml` for example) use environment variables to set Spring properties pointing at the database.

Comment: The question is more tricky than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below steps as a starting point, do not consider as production grade.

1. build the project using the build tool
2. Create a file with name `Dockerfile` in your project root to create docker image. add the following Docker commands in the `Dockerfile`

Suggested read: [What is docker image?](https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/definition/Docker-image)

```
# Alpine Linux with OpenJDK JRE
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# copy JAR into the image
COPY target/your_jar.jar /your_jar.jar

# run application with this command line
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=default", "/your_jar.jar"]
```

Now build a docker image using the following command:

```
docker build -t employee-service-image .
```

Now run the image

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 recruite_image
```

You can run MySQL Server in a separate container and pass the container's exposed port and IP address in the spring boot's application.properties.

Once you can build and run the image, try communicate with containers using `docker-compose`

[Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) 
[Getting started with Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

Comment: can you explain what exactly is going on the last line of the file CMD one? thanks

Comment: @bee `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` here first parameter is a executable command followed by parameters to the command. e.g. `CMD [ "echo", "Hello World!" ]`

Comment: thanks make sense and I have got it working :)